# What is the typical development workflow/process developing with Weborb for Java with Flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, weborb

Meaning specifically, what steps do you go through when creating a new application using these tools?

Comment: This site is worthless for tough questions. Had this been on a 'web forum' that had just as many users, there would be a worthwhile answer and real responses from 'hands-on' developers. Unfortunately there IS NOT a web forum out there with similar traffic, so it's either ask crickets elsewhere or get an honest inquiry closed here. Pathetic - this place is just Google-with-points. If I need to know how to create 'hello world' or any other basic no-real-world-experience-necessary answers I'll use Google, thanks. Too many close happy control freaks more interested in formalities than helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking out this [WebOrb 101 tutorial](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/weborb-101).

Then read through some docs about Adobe Flex.  [Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/) is a good start.  [Other resources are on the Adobe Support Page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/).

Then come back to us with specific questions.